# Running a hello world HElib program

Tags: c++

After going over this tutorial

http://tommd.github.io/

which uses the HElib library:
https://github.com/shaih/HElib

I get the following output:

The output is getting corrupted.  Given that the example has Level 16, there should be plenty of room to perform these operations.

Is there a problem with the parameters ?

Code:

```
#include "FHE.h"
#include "EncryptedArray.h"
#include <NTL/lzz_pXFactoring.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <sys/time.h>

using namespace std;
/**
 *
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

     /* On our trusted system we generate a new key
     * (or read one in) and encrypt the secret data set.
     */

    long m=0, p=2, r=1; // Native plaintext space
                        // Computations will be 'modulo p'
    long L=16;          // Levels
    long c=3;           // Columns in key switching matrix
    long w=64;          // Hamming weight of secret key
    long d=0;
    long security = 128;
    ZZX G;
    m = FindM(security,L,c,p, d, 0, 0);

    FHEcontext context(m, p, r);
    // initialize context
    buildModChain(context, L, c);
    // modify the context, adding primes to the modulus chain
    FHESecKey secretKey(context);
    // construct a secret key structure
    const FHEPubKey& publicKey = secretKey;
    // an "upcast": FHESecKey is a subclass of FHEPubKey

    //if(0 == d)
    G = context.alMod.getFactorsOverZZ()[0];

   secretKey.GenSecKey(w);
   // actually generate a secret key with Hamming weight w

   addSome1DMatrices(secretKey);
   cout << "Generated key" << endl;


   EncryptedArray ea(context, G);
   // constuct an Encrypted array object ea that is
   // associated with the given context and the polynomial G

   long nslots = ea.size();

   vector<long> v1;
   for(int i = 0 ; i < nslots; i++) {
       v1.push_back(i*2);
   }
   Ctxt ct1(publicKey);
   ea.encrypt(ct1, publicKey, v1);

   vector<long> v2;
   Ctxt ct2(publicKey);
   for(int i = 0 ; i < nslots; i++) {
       v2.push_back(i*3);
   }
   ea.encrypt(ct2, publicKey, v2);

     // On the public (untrusted) system we
   // can now perform our computation

   Ctxt ctSum = ct1;
   Ctxt ctProd = ct1;

   ctSum += ct2;
   ctProd *= ct2;


     vector<long> res;
    ea.decrypt(ctSum, secretKey, res);

    cout << "All computations are modulo " << p << "." << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < res.size(); i ++) {
        cout << v1[i] << " + " << v2[i] << " = " << res[i] << endl;
    }

    ea.decrypt(ctProd, secretKey, res);
    for(int i = 0; i < res.size(); i ++) {
        cout << v1[i] << " * " << v2[i] << " = " << res[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Generated key
All computations are modulo 2.

0 + 0 = 0
2 + 3 = 1
4 + 6 = 0
6 + 9 = 1
8 + 12 = 0
10 + 15 = 1
12 + 18 = 0
14 + 21 = 1
16 + 24 = 0
18 + 27 = 1
20 + 30 = 0
22 + 33 = 1
24 + 36 = 0
26 + 39 = 1
28 + 42 = 0
30 + 45 = 1
32 + 48 = 0
34 + 51 = 1
36 + 54 = 0
38 + 57 = 1
40 + 60 = 0
42 + 63 = 1
44 + 66 = 0
46 + 69 = 1
48 + 72 = 0
50 + 75 = 1
52 + 78 = 0
54 + 81 = 1
56 + 84 = 0
58 + 87 = 1
60 + 90 = 0

... Some sum output omitted

0 * 0 = 0
2 * 3 = 0
4 * 6 = 0
6 * 9 = 0
8 * 12 = 0
10 * 15 = 0
12 * 18 = 0
14 * 21 = 0
16 * 24 = 0
18 * 27 = 0
20 * 30 = 0
22 * 33 = 0
24 * 36 = 0
26 * 39 = 0
28 * 42 = 0
30 * 45 = 0
32 * 48 = 0
34 * 51 = 0
36 * 54 = 0
38 * 57 = 0
40 * 60 = 0
42 * 63 = 0
44 * 66 = 0
46 * 69 = 0
48 * 72 = 0
50 * 75 = 0
52 * 78 = 0
54 * 81 = 0
56 * 84 = 0
58 * 87 = 0
60 * 90 = 0
62 * 93 = 0
64 * 96 = 0
66 * 99 = 0
68 * 102 = 0
70 * 105 = 0
72 * 108 = 0
74 * 111 = 0
76 * 114 = 0
78 * 117 = 0
80 * 120 = 0
82 * 123 = 0
84 * 126 = 0
86 * 129 = 0

....

Comment: Perhaps if you supplied some more data we would be better able to predict what your code looks like?

Comment: The code is copy/pasted from the blogged referenced with no change.  Nevertheless, the answer is updated with it.

Comment: Could you explain why you think the output is corrupted?  The issue is not yet clear.

Comment: 0+0=0, this is correct
2+3=1 ?
2+3 should equal 5 correct ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, so this is a misunderstanding of the operations being performed.  Notice the constant `p=2`.  I have the text `All computations are modulo 2.`.  Perhaps also stating `All inputs are modulo 2` would help hammer the point home.  Lets look at some of our computations:

```
0 + 0 mod 2 = 0
2 + 3 mod 2 = 1
4 + 6 mod 2 = 0
6 + 9 mod 2 = 1
```

All looks good - addition ring 2 is just exclusive OR.  How about multiplication?  In ring 2 (binary) that's just AND:

```
0 * 0 = 0
2 * 3 = 6 mod 2 = 0
4 * 6 = 24 mod 2 = 0
6 * 9 = 54 mod 2 = 0
```

So that all checks out as well.  Finally, look back at the blog and see that I called this out again and give you a way to operate on something you might consider more pleasing:

> In this case, I am building for GF(2) - so my homormorphic addition
>   is XOR and multiplication is AND. Changing this is as easy as changing
>   the value of p. Folks wanting to see 2+2=4 should set p to something
>   that matches their desired domain, such as 257 to obtain 8 bit Ints.

However, HELib has regressed in this aspect - setting `p` equal to anything larger than `2` did not work last time I tried it.  Shai confirmed this is a known regression.